# Understanding better ExecutionReport QuickFix

Tags: quickfix

I am newbie on Fix in general and I have started from QuickFix to make practice. I apology in advance from the following trivial questions.

I have understood that to handle ExecutionReport I need to use crack() method inside FromApp() and implementing OnMessage().

But what I have two questions :

1) What happens if during a Partially fill order ExecutionReport message suddenly session drops, which is the  way to handle this situation. Trying to reconnect and Send a request ? Please Can you provide a simple explanation in steps and what QuickFix Api method should I use ?

2) If I need to implement a FixEngine to handle dropcopy should I be aware of something in particular ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

1). Just make sure `ResetOnDisconnect` parameter is set to `N` for your trading session: `ResetOnDisconnect=N` ([docs](http://quickfixn.org/tutorial/configuration.html))

- QuickFix will be automatically attempting to reconnect every `ReconnectInterval` seconds;
- Once connected (with `ResetOnDisconnect=N`) it will also automatically exchange last known message sequence numbers with the FIX server, and the ones lost during the disconnection will be re-sent - so without a line of code you will receive the missing messages.

Also, if disconnection was for a longer period of time, you may want to send `Order Status Request (H)` message to the FIX server to receive actual `ExecutionReport` for your pending orders.

2) The question is too general for me to answer...